# How can I cap a broken spigot standpipe?

Tags: plumbing, exterior, spigot

I have a water spigot that is connected to a private well. The PVC pipe about 1 foot into the ground cracked. Can I cement it in to use my other hose?

Basically I had the hose connected to the water spigot, yanked on it and it cracked the entire PVC pipe. Unfortunately, it cracked it at the connection so I can’t remove the cracked pipe and put another one on--I’d have to dig up the pipe. I have 3 other spigots connected to this private well, but can’t use them because if I turn the water on the broken pop shoots water up like a volcano.

Thinking about just getting rid of this pipe, and having 3 instead of 4, but how does one do that? Can I just cement it in?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain **cementing** does it mean glueing ?

Comment: What are we looking at here? What's the hexagonal part?

Answer (score 5):

If by "cementing" you mean encasing it in concrete, I would say No. The best bet is to dig it up, making a large enough space around the buried pipe that you can get it dry and work on it. Then cut it off and splice a new section of matching pipe to it using PVC primer and PVC cement. I agree with a comment above - you need to secure a plastic pipe to a solid post - plastic is not strong enough to take any abuse, and it will get brittle over time. If you want to abandon it, follow the same steps - just glue a PVC cap over the cut end instead of a coupling.